# What will happen if i wear 2 different Legendaries? (hook and beard)

Tags: dota-2

If you wear "Hook of the Basilisk" AND "Crazed Tassels of the Black Death", what custom icons will you have? Because the hook and the beard provides ability custom icons (as they are Legendary).

Comment: Do you own the items? Because nobody here is able to test it out.

Comment: No, i don't have these items. That's why i am asking :/

Comment: @aytimothy how do you know that nobody here is able to test that?

Comment: Let's just wait for an answer shall we? @DropDeadSander-EUW

Comment: You will die, the world will implode, and all the toast will burn.

Comment: you can try any items in the dota 2 test client and look for yourself ;) : https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/2mt1rn/how_to_use_phantom_assassin_arcana_dota_2_test/

Answer (score 1):

Tassel will override. I don't know reason behind it, but I tested it myself. And if you think it changes icon because it legendary, you're wrong. Its just happened like that, legendary not always change icon.

Answer (score 0):

Only the tassel icon effect shows up. Unfortunately. :/